# Finding the average value of a list through an enum in python

Tags: python, list, enums

For a school project I need to find the average value of a list through its elements. However these elements are not regular integers and part of an Enum. An example here :

My plan is to add the name of the dish (in this case) to another list and add the average to it as well, with the final result being planned to look like

[Dish_1, D1_value, Dish_2, D2_value]... etc

```
from enum import Enum;
class Ing(Enum):
    Water = 0
    Sugar = 1
    Apple = 2
    Flour = 3

Dish1 = ["Apple Pie", Ing.Water, Ing.Sugar, Ing.Apple, Ing.Flour];
Avg_All = [];
avg_all.append(Dish1[0]);
Dish1.pop(0);
```

And this is where I get stuck with finding out how to find the average

I tried using the mean function from the statistics library, but it gave this error
AttributeError: 'Rank' object has no attribute 'numerator'

Comment: Since the enum values have no inherent meaning on their own, what does the average value of those meaningless numbers represent?

Answer (score 1):

```
from enum import Enum
from statistics import mean

class Ing(Enum):
    Water = 0
    Sugar = 1
    Apple = 2
    Flour = 3

Dish1 = ["Apple Pie", Ing.Water, Ing.Sugar, Ing.Apple, Ing.Flour]

# Using mean function calcualtinf the mean of the Dish (Mean data is from index 1 to last)
average_value = mean([ingredient.value for ingredient in Dish1[1:]]) 

Avg_All = [Dish1[0], average_value]

print(Avg_All) # ['Apple Pie', 1.5]
```

If you have a list of Dishes Like

```
Dishes = [["Apple Pie", Ing.Water, Ing.Sugar, Ing.Apple, Ing.Flour], ["Xyz", Ing.Water, Ing.Sugar, Ing.Apple, Ing.Flour]]

# Then you can use this way.
Avg_All = []

for dish in Dishes:
    average_value = mean([ingredient.value for ingredient in dish[1:]]) 
    Avg_All.append([dish[0], average_value])

print(Avg_All) # [['Apple Pie', 1.5], ['Xyz', 1.5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a list of dishes and their ingredients as lists (dictionaries would make more sense but that's not what you have) then:

```
from enum import Enum

class Ing(Enum):
    Water = 0
    Sugar = 1
    Apple = 2
    Flour = 3
    Milk = 4
    Egg = 5

def mean(values):
    return sum(v := list(values)) / len(v)

Dishes = [
    ["Apple Pie", Ing.Water, Ing.Sugar, Ing.Apple, Ing.Flour],
    ['Pancake', Ing.Milk, Ing.Flour, Ing.Egg]
]

result = []

for dish, *ingredients in Dishes:
    result.extend([dish, mean(v.value for v in ingredients)])

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['Apple Pie', 1.5, 'Pancake', 4]
```

...which is a rather unusual way of presenting the result but that's what the question asks for